# How to generate multiple headers as a map using OpenAPI Generator?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I have the following two headers in my OpenAPI 2.0 definition:

```json
      {
        "name": "key",
        "in": "header",
        "description": "v4 UUID ",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string",
        "format": "string",
        "x-example": "d1257cae-9814-90d0-89e0-abd9ae7b3375"
      },
      {
        "name": "emp-number",
        "in": "header",
        "description": "The emp number",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string",
        "x-example": "43234"
      },
```

The implementation class generated by the OpenAPI Generator comes with two params for the headers:

```
makeXy(String key, String emp-number)
```

Is it possible to combine those two headers and generate them as a map? Like so:

```
makeXy(Map<String, String> headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenApi generator uses mustache templates to generate code. For Spring you find these templates here:

https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/JavaSpring

In `api.mustache` you find `{{>headerParams}}`. This is a mustache partial that is a way to reuse the same template code in multiple places. Here it means, include the `headerParams.mustache` at this place.

In `headerParams.mustache`, you will find that headers are included one by one.

In summary, it is not possible to to generate a Map of multiple header parameters (at least not by default configuration mechanism).